# DB connection error with Django: MariaDB Strict Mode is not set

Tags: django, mariadb

It won't let me do the migrations, I get this error

```
\(env) C:\\Users\\Mercadotecnia\\PycharmProjects\\practica\>python manage.py migrate
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MariaDB Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
HINT: MariaDB's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MariaDB, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Libro(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Titulo")
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes/', verbose_name="Imagen", null=True),
    descripcion = models.TextField(verbose_name="Descripcion", null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Libro'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is a Python script defining a model for a "Libro" object using Django's object-relational mapping (ORM) system.

The Libro class inherits from models.Model, which provides basic functionality for interacting with a database.

The Libro class has three fields: id, titulo, imagen, and descripcion, defined as class variables. id is an auto-incrementing integer field used as a primary key. titulo is a character field with a maximum length of 100 characters. imagen is an ImageField that stores uploaded image files in a directory named 'imagenes/' and descripcion is a text field.

The class Meta inside the Libro class is used to provide metadata for the model. In this case, the db_table attribute specifies the name of the database table that will be used to store instances of this model.

Note that the trailing comma after null=True) in the imagen field definition is unnecessary and can be removed.

This code defines the structure of the database table for the Libro model. To use this model in a Django web application, you will need to include it in your INSTALLED_APPS setting and create database migrations using Django's makemigrations and migrate commands.